# Hash function used in the TTTD chunking algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Can someone tell me where to find implementation of TTTD (Two Threshold Two Divisor) content-based chunking algorithm? Basically I want to know the hash function used in this? I am unable to find any useful link on Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TTTD chunking algorithm](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-30R1.html), like the Basic Sliding Window chunking algorithm it's based on, needs to compute a hash of every *n*-byte window over the file.

Thus, for maximal performance, it's desirable to choose a hash function that allows the hash value to be efficiently updated as the window is shifted forward by one byte.  For example, if the window size was 8 bytes, the current content of the window was `foobarba` and the next byte was `z`, we would like to be able to efficiently compute H(`oobarbaz`) based on H(`foobarba`).

There are several [rolling hash functions](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) that could be used for this purpose, but apparently the usual method, as mentioned in the TTTD paper linked above, is [Rabin fingerprinting](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint), which is based on finite field arithmetic.  The Wikipedia pages I linked to provide a brief overview of the algorithm, and include links to additional material.

Comment: No no. Its not cyclic i guess, after **z**, hash value will be updated and new value will be for **foobarbaz** and this will be checked if there is a break-point or not.
And Rabin-Karp algo is other thing, i don't think TTTD uses that?

Comment: I do believe you are mistaken. If the hash was not calculated over a rolling window of limited length, but simply over each prefix of the file, then a single prepended byte would completely change all the breakpoints.

Comment: This is the [pseudo-code](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/rws_etd/document/get/osu1337798801/inline) for TTTD algorithm. TTTD uses a variable length window.

Comment: The pseudo-code in Figure 3 in that thesis is copied verbatim from Appendix A of the original [HP tech report](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2005/HPL-2005-30R1.html) I linked to. The `updateHash()` function in it implicitly discards the first byte of the previous window while appending the next byte. To quote the tech report itself: "*`updateHash(c)` moves the sliding window, updating the hash by adding `c` and removing the character that is now not in the window.*"

Comment: Okie. Now I get it. That will do :D
Thanks.

Comment: @suri Please consider to mark an answer as accepted once your problem is solved. This is how Stackoverflow works.